Why do some windows .exe's have a .ico file in addition to a RT_GROUP_ICON?
As I understand it, when you're looking at a folder in Explorer, a binary's icon is determined by RT_GROUP_ICON within .rsrc. But many applications get distributed with a bin/program_name.ico file. What is that file for, if not for use by the binary?
For a particular example, I'm looking at PyCharm. C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2023.2.5\bin contains:
pycharm64.exe
pycharm.ico

